# Jasmine 2.0: how to use data from a single ajax call for all unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to avoid running an ajax call before each test in Jasmine.
Instead I would like to use data from single ajax call for all the tests, is there a way to do this?

Currently I am using beforeEach like this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/vulnerability/data',
        success: function (response) {
            done();
        },
    dataType: 'html'
    });
});

it("test 1", function() {
    // ajax is called for the 1st time
    // this won't run until the done callback is invoked from the beforeEach
});

it("test 2", function() {
    // ajax is called for the 2nd time
    // this won't run until the done callback is invoked from the beforeEach
});

it("test N", function() {
    // ajax is called for the Nth time
    // this won't run until the done callback is invoked from the beforeEach
});
```

Comment: In Jasmine 2.1 you can use `beforeAll` http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-10 .  
  In previous versions this plugin: https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll

Comment: Ahhh, nice, thats the perfect solution, thank you